# IndexOutOfBounds exception while trying to convert a folder contents into a zip file

Tags: android, kotlin, android-file

I have a requirement where I have two folders and each of them have to be converted into their respective zip files. Here is the current code  I am using.

```
fun zipFolder(inputFolderPath: String, outZipPath: String) {
    try {
        val fos = FileOutputStream(outZipPath)
        val zos = ZipOutputStream(fos)
        val srcFile = File(inputFolderPath)
        if (!srcFile.exists()) {
            Timber.e("Src file ${srcFile.path} does not exist..")
            return
        }
        val files = srcFile.listFiles()
        Timber.d("Zip directory: " + srcFile.name)
        for (i in files.indices) {
            Log.d("", "Adding file: " + files[i].name)
            val buffer = ByteArray(2048)
            val fis = FileInputStream(files[i])
            zos.putNextEntry(ZipEntry(files[i].name))
            while (fis.read(buffer) > 0) {
                zos.write(buffer, 0, fis.read(buffer))
            }
            zos.closeEntry()
            fis.close()
        }
        zos.close()
    } catch (e: IOException) {
        Timber.e(e)
    }

}
```

But for some reason, I am getting IndexOutOfBounds exception duting this process.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=234, result=-1, data=Intent { cmp=proj.com.wimwiiftkagent/proj.com.inspection.ui.InspectionProcedureActivity (has extras) }} to activity {proj.com.wimwiiftkagent/proj.com.wimwiiftkagent.ui.inspection.InspectionActivity}: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4440)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4484)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap19(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1743)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6753)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:482)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
     Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
        at java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream.write(ZipOutputStream.java:322)
        at proj.com.wimwiiftkagent.utils.FileUtils.zipFolder(FileUtils.kt:31)
        at proj.com.wimwiiftkagent.ui.inspection.InspectionActivity.processInspectionData(InspectionActivity.kt:59)
        at proj.com.wimwiiftkagent.ui.inspection.InspectionActivity.onActivityResult(InspectionActivity.kt:77)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:7317)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4436)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4484) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap19(Unknown Source:0) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1743) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6753) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:482) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

Do not worry about `Failure delivering result`. It is just because this compression code is called from `onActivityResult()` callback as the folder path's to be compressed is passed as result from a different activity.

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Could it be in your while loop you are calling fis.read(buffer) in the loop part, and in the loop body. Try setting a variable when you do the while check.

```
while (val data = fis.read(buffer)) {
    zos.write(buffer, 0, data)
}
```

Comment: it looks like we cannot do an assignment inside a while loop in kotlin . Android studio is showing me an error.

Comment: How about a do{} while() loop, 
val data = fis.read(buffer) then check that it is not null in the while after

Comment: I did try that. Didn't work. Getting the same OutOfBounds exception.

Answer (score 0):

The typical Java syntax for this is:

```
int c;
while ((c = fid.read(buffer)) >= 0) {
   zos.write(buffer, 0, c);
}
```

You can't do the same in Kotlin because an assignment is not an expression; to do the same in Kotlin you need a do/while loop with an `if` and a `break`.

But there is little need for that; Kotlin's standard library has an extension function that handles this for you: `copyTo`. And if you use the `use` method, you don't have to handle the closing of the input stream either. Which turns your method into:

```
for (f in files) {
    Log.d("", "Adding file: " + f.name)
    zos.putNextEntry(ZipEntry(f.name))
    val fis = FileInputStream(f)
    fis.use { fis.copyTo(zos, 2048) }
    zos.closeEntry()
}
```

Comment: Thanks. The function executes without crashing. But when I open the zip file, I get this error, "Unexpected end of archive"

Comment: My guess is, that you got an IO exception because the directory that you're zipping also contains subdirectories, that you can't open with a `FileInputStream`. You could change one line to ensure that you're only trying to zip files (and you should handle exceptions as well) `val files = srcFile.listFiles().filter(File::isFile)`

Comment: Actually, all that folder contains is some images. There are no subdirectories in the folder.